# Search for multiple occurrences of a single expression in a line

Tags: python, unix, sed

I have a dataset with two columns:

1. A decimal number
2. A long string

From the second column I would like to extract each FBtr number (e.g., FBtr0072798) and ignore the rest.

```
 0.850359 EFF=INTRON(MODIFIER|||||drpr|||FBtr0072798|4|1),INTRON(MODIFIER|||||drpr|||FBtr0072799|4|1),INTRON(MODIFIER|||||drpr|||FBtr0309845|4|1),SYNONYMOUS_CODING(LOW|SILENT|atT/atA|I690||CG18171|||FBtr0072800|1|1)
 0.473555 EFF=INTRON(MODIFIER|||||drpr|||FBtr0072798|4|1),INTRON(MODIFIER|||||drpr|||FBtr0072799|4|1),INTRON(MODIFIER|||||drpr|||FBtr0309845|4|1),SYNONYMOUS_CODING(LOW|SILENT|agC/agT|S371||CG18171|||FBtr0072800|1|1),UPSTREAM(MODIFIER|||||CG12035|||FBtr0072766||1)
 0.969735 EFF=INTRON(MODIFIER|||||drpr|||FBtr0072798|4|1),INTRON(MODIFIER|||||drpr|||FBtr0072799|4|1),INTRON(MODIFIER|||||drpr|||FBtr0309845|4|1),SYNONYMOUS_CODING(LOW|SILENT|gtT/gtC|V366||CG18171|||FBtr0072800|1|1),UPSTREAM(MODIFIER|||||CG12035|||FBtr0072766||1)
```

I would eventually like to transpose this into a long format, so that every line contains the decimal number from the first column, paired with a single FBtr number.  E.g.,

```
 0.850359   FBtr0072798
 0.850359   FBtr0072799
 0.850359   FBtr0309845
 0.850359   FBtr0072800
 0.473555   FBtr0072798
 0.473555   FBtr0072799
 0.473555   FBtr0309845
 0.473555   FBtr0072800
 0.473555   FBtr0072766
 0.969735   FBtr0072798
 0.969735   FBtr0072799
 0.969735   FBtr0309845
 0.969735   FBtr0072800
 0.969735   FBtr0072766
```

I have been attempting to do this in a stepwise way, first extracting the FBtr number into a separate column:

```
 0.850359   FBtr0072798 FBtr0072799 FBtr0309845 FBtr0072800
 0.473555   FBtr0072798 FBtr0072799 FBtr0309845 FBtr0072800 FBtr0072766
 0.969735   FBtr0072798 FBtr0072799 FBtr0309845 FBtr0072800 FBtr0072766
```

Then transforming from wide to long format.

Right now I am having issues extracting the FBtr number.  I am ever more novice at python than unix so I have been trying to use unix because I am a bit more comfortable with the language. The most promising thing I have tried so far has been using sed to do a find/replace searching for each of the terms repetitively.

```
 sed -e 's/\(.* \).*\(FBtr[0-9]*\).*\(FBtr[0-9]*\).*\(FBtr[0-9]*\).*\(FBtr[0-9]*\).*\(FBtr[0-9]*\).*/ \1 \2 \3 \4 \5 \6/ g' file.txt
```

This is not only ugly with all of the repeats, but only works if there are the same number of FBtr occurrences in row, which unfortunately there are not. Any thoughts on how to approach this problem in either unix or python?

Comment: If you can use `GNU Awk`, refer my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is little python program which I think meets your requirements.  It uses `str.split()` and `str.startswith()` to find all of the occurrences of strings starting with `FBtr`.

**Code:**

```
for line in test_data:
    num, string = line.split(' ', 1)
    for field in string.split('|'):
        if field.startswith('FBtr'):
            print(num, field)
```

**Test Data:**

```
test_data = [x.strip() for x in """
    0.850359 EFF=INTRON(MODIFIER|||||drpr|||FBtr0072798|4|1),INTRON(MODIFIER|||||drpr|||FBtr0072799|4|1),INTRON(MODIFIER|||||drpr|||FBtr0309845|4|1),SYNONYMOUS_CODING(LOW|SILENT|atT/atA|I690||CG18171|||FBtr0072800|1|1)
    0.473555 EFF=INTRON(MODIFIER|||||drpr|||FBtr0072798|4|1),INTRON(MODIFIER|||||drpr|||FBtr0072799|4|1),INTRON(MODIFIER|||||drpr|||FBtr0309845|4|1),SYNONYMOUS_CODING(LOW|SILENT|agC/agT|S371||CG18171|||FBtr0072800|1|1),UPSTREAM(MODIFIER|||||CG12035|||FBtr0072766||1)
    0.969735 EFF=INTRON(MODIFIER|||||drpr|||FBtr0072798|4|1),INTRON(MODIFIER|||||drpr|||FBtr0072799|4|1),INTRON(MODIFIER|||||drpr|||FBtr0309845|4|1),SYNONYMOUS_CODING(LOW|SILENT|gtT/gtC|V366||CG18171|||FBtr0072800|1|1),UPSTREAM(MODIFIER|||||CG12035|||FBtr0072766||1)
""".split('\n')[1:-1]]
```

**Gives Output:**

```
0.850359 FBtr0072798
0.850359 FBtr0072799
0.850359 FBtr0309845
0.850359 FBtr0072800
0.473555 FBtr0072798
0.473555 FBtr0072799
0.473555 FBtr0309845
0.473555 FBtr0072800
0.473555 FBtr0072766
0.969735 FBtr0072798
0.969735 FBtr0072799
0.969735 FBtr0309845
0.969735 FBtr0072800
0.969735 FBtr0072766
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use `GNU Awk` its `gensub()` function can be cool to make life *simpler* for you,

```
awk -F[[:space:],] '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if (match($i,/FBtr([[:digit:]]+)/)) \
     {value=gensub(/^.*FBtr([[:digit:]]+).*$/,"FBtr\\1","g",$i); print $2,value} }' file
0.850359 FBtr0072798
0.850359 FBtr0072799
0.850359 FBtr0309845
0.850359 FBtr0072800
0.473555 FBtr0072798
0.473555 FBtr0072799
0.473555 FBtr0309845
0.473555 FBtr0072800
0.473555 FBtr0072766
0.969735 FBtr0072798
0.969735 FBtr0072799
0.969735 FBtr0309845
0.969735 FBtr0072800
0.969735 FBtr0072766
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it is *simple* but it seems to work with one adjustment - print $1 instead of $2.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/\n/!s/FB[^|]*/\n&\n/g;s/^\s*(\S+)[^\n]*\n([^\n]*\n)/\1 \2\1 /;/FB/P;D' file
```

Isolate the `FB` strings using newlines. Then using matching and back references, construct the first record and prime the second, printing only lines that contain the `FB` strings and repeat until all current line is totally processed.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
line = '0.850359 EFF=INTRON(MODIFIER|||||drpr|||FBtr0072798|4|1),INTRON(MODIFIER|||||drpr|||FBtr0072799|4|1),INTRON(MODIFIER|||||drpr|||FBtr0309845|4|1),SYNONYMOUS_CODING(LOW|SILENT|atT/atA|I690||CG18171|||FBtr0072800|1|1)'
print(re.findall('FBtr(\d+)', line))
```

['0072798', '0072799', '0309845', '0072800']

Comment: Hi, could you please elaborate on your proposed answer? As it stands now, it's difficult to understand why it works.

Comment: [re.findall()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.findall) just finds all occurrences of regexp in string and returns them as list

Comment: if you change regexp to `'(FBtr)(\d+)'` result will be `[('FBtr', '0072798'), ('FBtr', '0072799'), ('FBtr', '0309845'), ('FBtr', '0072800')]`

Comment: In the answer, please.